# unable to integrate self hosted gitlab repo with reviewboard

Tags: gitlab, review-board

i am trying to integrate self hosted gitlab repo with review board runnning without ssl but getting this error. below is my configuration screenshot.

[configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADS6E.jpg)

error logs :

```
HostingServiceError: Unexpected HTTP error 502.
2017-07-13 13:14:26,852 - ERROR -  - root - Unexpected HTTP error when linking GitLab account for gauravs: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/gitlab.py", line 245, in authorize
    'password': password,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/service.py", line 383, in json_post
    return self._do_json_method(self.http_post, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/service.py", line 412, in _do_json_method
    data, headers = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/service.py", line 245, in http_post
    method='POST', **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/service.py", line 293, in http_request
    response = urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
2017-07-13 13:14:26,856 - ERROR -  - root - Unknown error linking hosting account ID=None for hosting service='gitlab', username=u'gauravs', LocalSite=None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/forms.py", line 348, in save
    **extra_authorize_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/gitlab.py", line 261, in authorize
    % e.code)
HostingServiceError: Unexpected HTTP error 502.
2017-07-13 13:14:26,857 - ERROR -  - root - Unexpected error when linking hosting service account on gitlab: Unexpected HTTP error 502.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/scmtools/forms.py", line 669, in _clean_hosting_info
    force_authorize=force_authorize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/forms.py", line 348, in save
    **extra_authorize_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reviewboard/hostingsvcs/gitlab.py", line 261, in authorize
    % e.code)
HostingServiceError: Unexpected HTTP error 502.
```

any leads how can this be fixed???
i didnt find anything wrong in the configuration and login credentials?

Comment: Have you tried 'Repository Type' 'HTTPS', if there is one?

Comment: @secustor no i didnt as we dont have ssl for that domain.. once i tried it gave connection refused error.

Comment: I have no experience with review board. Is there also a 'HTTP' option?

Comment: yes there is http option. there is some issue with the configuration i guess as it supports both http and https.